# Add sequence prefix to file names

Tags: windows, command-line, sed, awk, rename

I want to rename multiple files from the command line (I am using windows).
before rename:

```
fileA.txt
fileB.txt
fileC.txt
```

after rename:

```
1_fileA.txt
2_fileB.txt
3_fileC.txt
```

by the way , even that I am using windows but I have tools like sed,grep,awk...
but I cant find a way to use them

Comment: So `fileN.txt` will be moved to `N_fileN.txt` or the first number does not have to do with the second one?

Comment: no, the second number isn't important , anyway I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from the command line:

```
for /f "delims=: tokens=1,2" %A in ('dir /b *.txt^|findstr /n .') do @ren "%B" "%A_%B"
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using cygwin and bash:

```
$ n=1

$ ls
fileA.txt  fileB.txt  fileC.txt

$ for i in *.txt; do mv $i ${n}_${i}; ((n++)); done

$ ls
1_fileA.txt  2_fileB.txt  3_fileC.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set i=0
for %%a in (*.*) do (
    set /a i=i+1
    ren %%a !i!%%a
)
```

Save it to a file in a different directory, and go to the directory where the files exist. After that in a cmd.exe command prompt run:

```
call X:\path\to\file.bat
```

Basing on ls, awk, xargs and mv:

```
ls *.* | awk {printf("\"%s\""\x20""\"%d%s\"\n",$0,NR,$0)} | xargs mv
```

Comment: Why is it that you are not interested in a solution, and want some other tool to be used instead?

Comment: @user2776193 Don't you have a shell there like `sh`?

Comment: Yes, but and along awk, sed and grep, you could possibly have bash or sh as well.

Comment: @user2776193 If you like you could install cygwin. The default install settings of it would be enough. http://cygwin.com/install.html. You can also try winbash: http://sourceforge.net/projects/win-bash/ for having the shell only.

Comment: ls *.mkv | awk '{print "\"" $0 "\" s" $4 "e" $6}' | xargs mv

Comment: @user2776193 Try `ls *.* | awk '{printf("\"%s\" \"%d%s\"\n", $0, NR, $0)}' | xargs mv`.

Comment: @user2776193 Please try this one: `ls *.* | awk {printf("\"%s\""\x20""\"%d%s\"\n",$0,NR,$0)} | xargs mv`

Comment: I guess bash do make some internal quotings when it's in windows. Try this quoted form: `ls *.* | awk "{printf(\"\\\"%s\\\"\"\"\\x20\"\"\\\"%d%s\\\"\\n\",$0,NR,$0)}" | xargs mv`

Comment: other errors , maybe awk don't work well with cmd. now I will try with winbash

Comment: using winbash , awk worked but mv is giving error "mv: target `3fileC.txt' is not a directory"

Comment: @If you're at bash, try to add -1 option to ls: `ls -1 *.*`. Also Fredrick Pihl's [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18785640/445221) could be used for that already.

Comment: @user2776193 Reminds me you could just use `move` instead. `mv` must be requiring a directory.

Comment: Also try: `i=0; for f in *.txt; do move "$f" "$((++i))$f"; done`.

Comment: 'move' doesn't exist in winbash

Comment: by the way, I tried this command `i=0; for f in *.txt; do mv "$f" "$((++i))$f"; done` and this is the result https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31050955/result.JPG

Comment: @user2776193 You won't regret using cygwin :) The command should work well with it.

Comment: with cygwin , the command with awk didn't work. but this code `i=0; for f in *.txt; do mv "$f" "$((++i))$f"; done` worked well